# Principal component analysis alternative for categorical and continuous variables in matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, signal-processing, pca

In Matlab, I would like to do a principal component analysis but my data are a mixture of mainly categorical variables with a few continuous variables.

My data consists of columns that represent different variables, or example:

```
Name    Gender   Hair_color  Eye_color   Age    Height   Country
```

I have never done this type of analysis before, but from some searching I see that [this package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v31/i08) could possibly work?

Any suggestions and/or links to simple tutorial examples with this sort of data would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The stats.stackoverflow.com site has a great answer to this question - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont